# Generate GS1-128 using ZXing.Net

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing.net, gs1-128

We use ZXing.Net to generate code 128 barcode and everything works fine.

```
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter { Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 };
writer.Write("01950123456789031000012317150801").Save("code128.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

[image]

Recently we have been asked to change the format to GS1-128 and after some research we found this solution using FNC1 (ASCII 29) to write DataMatrix GS1.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43575418/823247

```
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter { Format = BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX };
writer.Write($"{(char)29}019501234567890310000123{(char)29}17150801").Save("gs1datamatrix.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

[image]

However, if we change the barcode format to `BarcodeFormat.CODE_128`, the program will throw exception showing `Bad character in input:`

```
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter { Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 };
writer.Write($"{(char)29}019501234567890310000123{(char)29}17150801").Save("gs1code128.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of "(char)29" you have to use the value "(char)0x00F1" as group separator.

Comment: Thanks! Work like a charm! Does this mean every barcode format has its own group separator?

Comment: Yes and no. I think 29 is the most common one. Not sure why there was chosen another one for GS1-128. But this two barcode types are the only ones which are supported by zxing for GS1.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier approach to generate **GS1-128** barcode via **Zxing.Net** without manually adding character FNC1 to content.

You should only set the flag **GS1Format = true**

```
barcodeWriterSvg.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
barcodeWriterSvg.Options.GS1Format = true;
barcodeWriterSvg.Options.Margin = 64;

var svgImage = barcodeWriterSvg.Write(content);
return svgImage.Content;
```

But the original solution based on manually adding FNC1 character to the beginning of string https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/wiki/Generating-GS1-DataMatrix-and-GS1-Code128-barcodes

Comment: At the moment the option GS1Format is only used by the QR code encoder. It only adds the GS1 format identificator FNC1 at the first position. There are not group separators or similar control characters added.